# Download Flash Video from Flickr

Tags: video, download, flash, swf, flickr

There is a [video](http://www.flickr.com/photos/forestwander-nature-pictures/5645318632/in/photostream/) I would like to download from Flickr (please note that video is Licensed under Created Commons)

I have tried Download Helper (FF Add-On) and it does not see the video. Also I have tried Orbit and again it does not see this video. I have tried to copy the SWF code directly from the HTML and it gives me a "this video is no longer available" error.

***EDIT*** - I attempted to download the file (in FF) using the Page Info button and I can download the SWF file but it doesn't play or work correctly.

How do I download this video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the URL-address of page and insert url-address into the [site](http://savevideo.me) and to press "Download",and 'HELLO' you will be prompted to either download a low quality FLV file or an MP4. Hope this might do the trick. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks that worked! One thing to note it does take a little bit (took a couple minutes for me). The MP4 came out looking nice. Thanks Again!

Comment: You are welcome! I know it takes some time.